# Remove ' ' from a Query String in C#

Tags: c#

Below is my hard quoted Oracle query and it runs fine itself.

```
SELECT F.*
      ,R.EARN_NAME
      ,R.EARN_TYPE
      ,D.DESIG_NAME
      ,D.DESIG_NO 
from FIXED_EARN_DETAILS F,
     EARNINGS R,
     DESIGNATION D 
WHERE F.FIXED_EARN_NO IN(
                       select max(FIXED_EARN_NO) 
                       FROM FIXED_EARN_DETAILS  
                       where DESIG_NO=(
                             SELECT DEPT_CODE 
                             FROM EMP_ALLOCATION 
                             WHERE EMP_NO='000507') 
                      GROUP BY earn_no) 
AND F.EARN_NO=R.EARN_NO 
AND D.DESIG_NO=F.DESIG_NO 
ORDER BY F.EARN_NO
```

Here is my C# query string

```
string strDesig_No="(SELECT DESIG_NO FROM EMP_ALLOCATION WHERE EMP_NO='000507')";

string  SelectQuery="SELECT F.*,R.EARN_NAME,R.EARN_TYPE,D.DESIG_NAME,D.DESIG_NO from FIXED_EARN_DETAILS F,EARNINGS R,DESIGNATION D WHERE F.FIXED_EARN_NO IN(select max(FIXED_EARN_NO) FROM FIXED_EARN_DETAILS  where DESIG_NO='" + strDesig_No + "' GROUP BY earn_no) AND F.EARN_NO=R.EARN_NO AND D.DESIG_NO=F.DESIG_NO ORDER BY F.EARN_NO";
```

So when I try to run this the final query always comes as follows where I find two extra commas '' beside the `(SELECT DEPT_CODE FROM EMP_ALLOCATION WHERE EMP_NO='000507')` and so the query fails.

```
SELECT F.*,R.EARN_NAME,R.EARN_TYPE,D.DESIG_NAME,D.DESIG_NO from FIXED_EARN_DETAILS F,EARNINGS R,DESIGNATION D WHERE F.FIXED_EARN_NO IN(select max(FIXED_EARN_NO) FROM FIXED_EARN_DETAILS  where DESIG_NO='(SELECT DEPT_CODE FROM EMP_ALLOCATION WHERE EMP_NO='000507')' GROUP BY earn_no) AND F.EARN_NO=R.EARN_NO AND D.DESIG_NO=F.DESIG_NO ORDER BY F.EARN_NO
```

Help me with this simple syntax error where I am stucked.

Comment: Use parameterized queries. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you mean to say you have extra quotes? you said commas...where DESIG_NO=" + strDesig_No + " GROUP BY earn_no

Comment: @TimSchmelter beat me to it, yeah definitely parameterized queries over string concatenation.

Comment: @montewhizdoh

yes, as this
 DESIG_NO='(SELECT DEPT_CODE FROM EMP_ALLOCATION WHERE EMP_NO='000507')' GROUP BY earn_no)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter

Can you simplify/detail it a bit plaease? I am a novice.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the single quotes yourself

```
string  SelectQuery="... where DESIG_NO='" + strDesig_No + "' GROUP ...";
                                        ^                   ^
```

if you don't add them, they won't be there.

Comment: If you remove  the ' ' of  ' " + strDesig_No + " '  it will support until the value is a number and when its a string the Oracle query fails

Comment: You shouldn't be passing values into the sql command like that - use parameter binding instead. Creating sql commands on the fly from known sub-clauses is generally OK, but values which may come from users should not be appended directly - nothing stops the string containing another quote and a semicolon - https://xkcd.com/327/ .

Answer (score 0):

But that not really a good way to do it, its too subjectable to injection and the code looks just ugly. You could just use parameter binding.

```
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT name FROM users
                           WHERE name = :userName", db);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("userName", userName));
```

Comment: What is this answer about ?

Comment: About the correct way to make a query that has a parameter.

Comment: How do I mange your suggestion with my query   >>  

        select max(FIXED_EARN_NO) FROM FIXED_EARN_DETAILS  where  DESIG_NO='" + strDesig_No + "' GROUP BY earn_no